# How do you convert raw scores into z scores to check for outliers?

Tags: r, outliers

I am comparing meanWQ and meanSPI scores of people with diagnosis 1 (GAD) and diagnosis 2 (SAD). 
I am using the following formula to convert the raw scores of my data frame into z scores to check for outliers:

```
dat$zmeanWQ<-scale(dat$meanWQ, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
which(zmeanWQ>=1.96 | zmeanWQ<=-1.96)

Error in which(zmeanWQ >= 1.96 | zmeanWQ <= -1.96) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': Error: object 'zmeanWQ' not found

dat$zmeanWQ<-scale(dat$meanWQ, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
which(zmeanWQ>=1.96 | zmeanWQ<=-1.96)

Error in which(zmeanWQ >= 1.96 | zmeanWQ <= -1.96) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': Error: object 'zmeanWQ' not found
```

My data frame has 3 diagnosis (0,1,2,3). I have also created a subset with just diagnosis 1 and 2, which is what I am currently analyzing. 
"dat" is the original data frame with all 4 diagnosis. "New" is the subset I created with diagnosis 1 and 2. All 4 diagnosis have a mean WQ and mean SPI column.

Comment: Your `which` cannot find `zmeanWQ` because it is not in your global environment. It is a vector of data.frame `dat`.

Comment: use indexing or `with(dat, which(zmeanWQ>=1.96 | zmeanWQ<=-1.96))`

Comment: Use `qnorm(0.975)` instead of `1.96` too, if you want to get technical.